# Turn array of comma delimited strings into distinct array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to take an array of objects:

```
var objArr = [
    {id:1, name:'test', seenby:'user1, user2, user3'},
    {id:2, name:'test1', seenby:'user3, user4'},
    {id:3, name:'test2', seenby:'user1, user3'},
    {id:4, name:'test3', seenby:'user2'}
];
```

And return a distinct array of all 'seenby' users:

```
var seenByArr = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4']
```

I can't figure out how to efficiently (fewest lines possible) turn this into an array of distinct values. Please check out my fiddle for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ksumarine/ss3v7dgj/

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil -- DonaldKnuth

Comment: Agreed, unfortunately that's the data I have to work with :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following

```
$.each(list, function(index, value) {
    $.each(value.seenby.split(","), function(i, val) {
        if (val !== undefined && val.trim() !== "" && arr.indexOf(val.trim()) == -1) {
            arr.push(val.trim());
        }
    });
});
```

For reference - https://jsfiddle.net/ss3v7dgj/1/

Comment: @ksumarine - Welcome

Answer (score 3):

I realize this question doesn't mention Underscore, but it's worth mentioning that [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) is a very popular library for manipulating objects and arrays, and well-suited for this kind of thing.

Here's a big unreadable single line for achieving this with Underscore:

```
_.unique(_.flatten(_.map(_.pluck(objArr, 'seenby'), function(seenby) { return seenby.split(', '); })))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I'm not using Underscore...though that solution does look great.

Answer (score 2):

The laconic solution with `String.split` and `Array.foreach` functions:

```
var arr = [];
objArr.forEach(function (obj) {
        var str = obj.seenby.split(',');
        str.forEach(function (v) {
            var user = v.trim();
            if (arr.indexOf(user) === -1) arr.push(user);
        });
});

console.log(arr);
// the output:
["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"]
```

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - You are using map function for which even a foreach function would have worked. Just trying to understand the use of map function at first place.

Comment: @nikhil, agreed, I've updated my solution. I've just made haste to provide a quick answer

Comment: I'd pick both for the accepted answer if I could. Thank you RomanPerekhrest and nikhil!

Answer (score 1):

A solution in plain Javascript with an IIFE and a temporary object for the items.

```js
var objArr = [{ id: 1, name: 'test', seenby: 'user1, user2, user3' }, { id: 2, name: 'test1', seenby: 'user3, user4' }, { id: 3, name: 'test2', seenby: 'user1, user3' }, { id: 4, name: 'test3', seenby: 'user2' }],
    result = function (array) {
        var obj = {}, r = [];
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            a.seenby.split(', ').forEach(function (b) {
                obj[b] = obj[b] || r.push(b);
            });
        });
        return r;
    }(objArr);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
given = function (x) {
    return {
        do: function (f) { x = f(x); return this },
        return: function () { return x }
    }
};

r = given(objArr)
    .do(x => x.map(y => y.seenby))
    .do(x => [].concat.apply([], x))
    .do(x => x.join(', '))
    .do(x => x.split(', '))
    .do(x => x.filter((e, i) => x.indexOf(e) === i))
    .do(x => x.sort())
    .return();
```

I might find use for this someday...

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, and de-duplicate the users in a associative array. So here the interesting part, but you can also try it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a_maze_d/hqb5sm10/):

```
var list = [
    {id:1, name:'test', seenby:'user1, user2, user3'},
    {id:2, name:'test1', seenby:'user3, user4'},
    {id:3, name:'test2', seenby:'user1, user3'},
    {id:4, name:'test3', seenby:'user2'}
];

var arr = [];
list.map(function(value){
        value.seenby.split(",").map(function(val){
      arr[val.trim()] = 1;
        });
});

var seenby = Object.keys(arr);
```

How does it work? The `map` function will iterate over all the `list` items, the next map will iterate over all the `seenby` items. We then collect the users in the `arr`, de-duplicating by using it as an associative array.
At the end we extract all the associative array keys by using the [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) function.

Minor caveat is that this solution will only work if the map function exists, if it doesn't you would need to implement it yourself. But usually you are using a new enough JavaScript version that does support it. This solution also has the nice side effect that you don't really need any external dependency (except of course for displaying it)

**UPDATE:**
I think it's actually better to do it the [following way](https://jsfiddle.net/a_maze_d/as0zdx4e/):

```
var arr = list
    .reduce(function(acc, value){
        return acc.concat(value.seenby.split(",").map(function(val){
            return val.trim()
    }))},[])
    .filter(function(item, index, array) {
        return array.indexOf(item) === index
    }
)
```

Explanation:

- we take the list and for each item, we reduce it ...

  - from each item, we extract the `seenby` field
  - we `split` the field
  - we `map` each item to `trim` it
- ... we take the array of returned `seenby` and concatenate them to our accumulator array `arr` (which is initialized as empty array `[]`)
- then we filter out the duplicates from the array (by checking whether the index of an item is the same as the current index)

Comment: This is great, thanks for the awesome explanation also.